# Bit shifting a double value in MATLAB R2010b

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to perform a bit shift right operation on a double value in MATLAB 2010b. It seems that in newer MATLAB versions, this can be done using [bitsra()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fixedpoint/ref/bitsra.html), e.g.:

```
y = double(128);
bitsra(y,3)
```

but this function is not available in older versions.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Numbers in MATLAB are doubles by default, so there is no need to write `y = double(128)`, `y = 128` gives the same result (`128 == double(128)` yields 1).

Comment: Do you literally want to shift the bits of a double, or do you just want to multiply and divide by powers of 2?

Comment: Note that bitsra is part of the fixed point toolbox, so NOT available to everyone.

Comment: I simply need to get the fixed point representation of a fraction which is done by scaling by 2^13, so I guess I can just multiply by 2^13.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`bitshift`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/fixedpoint/ref/bitshift.html) function, which is available from at least MATLAB 2009a. From the documentation

> `c = bitshift(a, k)` returns the value of `a` shifted by `k` bits.
>
> - When `k` is positive, 0-valued bits are shifted in on the right.
> - When `k` is negative, and `a` is unsigned, or a signed and positive, 0-valued bits are shifted in on the left.
> - When `k` is negative and `a` is a signed and negative, 1-valued bits are shifted in on the left.

On MATLAB 2012b

```
>> bitsra(128, 3)

ans =

    16
```

On MATLAB 2009a:

```
>> bitshift(128, -3)

ans =

    16
```

**Edit:** `bitshift` works with any *fixed-point* data type, although the error message generated by calling `bitshift(128.5, -3)` would suggest that it requires integer values. So `bitshift(128.5, -3)`, for example, will not work since `128.5` is, by default, a floating point double precision variable. From the documentation for `bitshift` you can use the `fi` function from the floating-point toolbox to create *fixed-point numbers*. So to work with fractions one could do something like

```
>> bitshift(fi(128.5), -3)

ans =

    16.025
```

Comment: The problem is that bitshift() only works on integers. I work with fractions.

Comment: `bitshift` works with any *fixed-point* data type. So 128.5, for example, will not work since this is, by default, a floating point double precision variable. From the documentation for `bitshift` you can use the `fi` function from the floating-point toolbox to create *fixed-point* numbers. See my edit.